# Z-index strip inside wrapper visible on the whole page

Tags: html, css

i would like to get to result  of the blue strip in the picture bellow.
Its inside the wrapper so the HTML is like this:

```
    <body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="strap"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

I know its done with z-index. The strap should be visible on the whole page. Thanks for help
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following CSS. The code sets the position to absolute and then positions each point of the div to each corner of the window, top, bottom, left and right. Z-index will bring it to the front. Ensure that there are no other elements that use z-index with a greater value than 99. The background color is then set as white with 40% transparency; Adjust the 0.6 to what you need it to be. 0.8 for example would be less transparent.

```
.strap{ 
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
z-index:99;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css attribute position absolute and use top,right,left,bottom for alignment. And use z index to make it appear on top of that wrapper make sure the width is 100% ...

Comment: yes i tried this, but the strap appears just on the right part.    https://imgur.com/a/z4WYkeb